# Object 'count' not found during construction of contingency table in R

Tags: r

I have the data deaths:

```
 victim defendant deathpen count
[1,] white  white     yes      53   
[2,] white  black     yes      11   
[3,] black  white     yes      0    
[4,] black  black     yes      4    
[5,] white  white     no       414  
[6,] white  black     no       37   
[7,] black  white     no       16   
[8,] black  black     no       139
```

I am trying to create a three way contingency table based off of victim and defendant and how it plays a role in death penalty. I am trying to create tabs, but for some reason it will not recognize my column names with the given code:

```
deaths.tabs=xtabs(count~victim+defendant+deathpen,data=deaths).  
Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'count' not found
```

Here is the code I used to create the table in the first place:

```
deaths=matrix(c("white","white","yes",53,"white","black","yes",11,"black","white","yes",0, 
"black","black","yes",4,"white","white","no",414,"white","black","no",37,"black","white","no",16,"black","black","no",139),nrow=8,byrow=TRUE)
```

I then used `noquote()` to get rid of the quotation marks in the data.

If anyone could help me out in getting the following table into R, that would be much appreciated:

pic of table I am trying to mimic

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Someone who is better with matrices would have a cleaner answer, but I would convert to a dataframe because I find them easier to work with. Also, your `xtabs` line is assuming that each of those vectors `count`,`victim`, etc. are contained in a dataframe with `data=deaths`. In your matrix, none of these columns have names:

```
deaths=matrix(c("white","white","yes",53,"white","black","yes",11,"black","white","yes",0, "black","black","yes",4,"white","white","no",414,"white","black","no",37,"black","white","no",16,"black","black","no",139),nrow=8,byrow=TRUE)

deaths<-as.data.frame(deaths)
names(deaths)<-c("victim","defendant","deathpen","count") # you didn't provide header names, but we have to tell the data frame what things are called. You can do this easier if you read in data from a .csv or otherwise directly into a dataframe.
deaths$count<-as.numeric(deaths$count) # change class to numeric, because it is defaulted to a character
deaths.tabs=xtabs(count~victim+defendant+deathpen,data=deaths)

deaths.tabs
, , deathpen = no

       defendant
victim  black white
  black   139    16
  white    37   414

, , deathpen = yes

       defendant
victim  black white
  black     4     0
  white    11    53
```

Now you just need to make the table look appealing. See: https://rdrr.io/cran/epitab/man/neat_table.html

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/kableExtra/vignettes/awesome_table_in_html.html

https://stuartlacy.co.uk/2017/11/13/epitab-contingency-tables-in-r/